# Is there a way to give someone access GitHub issues without giving them read access to the source code?

Tags: github

We have a GitHub organization setup with private repositories. We would like to give a few of our beta testers access to add and comment on issue but we don't want to give them access to the source code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, due to the way issues are directly linked to commits.

Comment: It may not be possible but I don't think thats would be the reason. The commits aren't shown, they are linked to. The links would do the same thing as if you typed in the url of a repo you didn't have acces to.

Comment: this is not entirely accurate as gitHub has a good workaround

Answer (score 4):

See here:

https://help.github.com/articles/issues-only-access-permissions

Indeed you can do what you want to achieve, you just need to have a second repository for that purpose.

Comment: This work around has been floating around for a long time. At least you can close issues across repos now but the likely hood of typos when you need to type that much just to reference an issue number is quite high. That makes this an unreliable hack at best.